# Login Wallpaper Spanning Dual Monitors in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, login-screen, desktop-background

Is there a way to make the background on the login screen span dual monitors rather than being mirrored? I know it's possible for the actual wallpaper when you're logged in but can't find an option for the login background.